# Can I have a PWA without caching any assets?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I want to use a PWA to allow my small app to be installable, but there is no real need for it to be 'offline ready' - it's a vue app that is constantly calling the server for data and it simply does not work without the network.

If I have a serviceworker that does not bother to cache anything, can I still install it to the device homescreen as per usual, and does it simply request all assets every time it loads up? Are there other limitations here?

Comment: Could always cache the basics which doesn't take much effort and have a route to go to when offline that just says "Sorry, not now". Some PWA seed projects cache enough without needing to doing anything other than minor manifest tweaks

Comment: Yes, you can cache as many or as few assets as you want

Comment: What about chromes requirement for the web manifests `start_url` to serve a 200 when offline?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can cache your vue.js `index.html`, and if you want, that will resolve as the answer for the 200 offline problem.
As vue.js implements the SPA model, the whole application will be controlled by the JS, even the routes, so just make sure you don't cache your dist js file.